# Spell and cooldown system for an Unity game

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity3d

So I have doubts about my code and if it is any good. I have a parent class Spell:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spell : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum SpellType { AttackType, AreaType, BuffType, DebuffType };

    public float damage;
    public float speed;
    public float cooldowntime;
    public SpellType type;

    public Spell()
    {

    }

    void Start () {

    }

    protected void Update () {
        if(type == SpellType.AttackType)
        {
            updateSpell();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void updateSpell()
    {

    }

    protected void deleteSpell()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Monster")
        {
            Interface.IMonster inter = other.GetComponent<Interface.IMonster>();
            inter.takeDamage(damage);
            deleteSpell();
        }
    }
}
```

Then one of the child classes:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

class WaterBolt : Spell
{
    private Vector3 mouseposition;
    private Vector3 screenpoint;
    private Vector2 offset;
    private float angle;

    void Start()
    {
        mouseposition = Input.mousePosition;
        screenpoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.localPosition);
        offset = new Vector2(mouseposition.x - screenpoint.x, mouseposition.y - screenpoint.y);
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);

        Invoke("deleteSpell", 5f);
    }

    protected override void updateSpell()
    {
        transform.position += transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
```

Then this is what pretty much displays and drives the spell system with cooldown. Its a bit long and I would like to shorten but I can't think of something that would help.
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GuiSpellHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;
    public int activenumber = 0;
    public GameObject spell1, spell2, spell3, spell4, spell5, spell6, spell7, spell8;
    public float spellcooldown1, spellcooldown2, spellcooldown3, spellcooldown4, spellcooldown5, 
                spellcooldown6, spellcooldown7, spellcooldown8;
    float spellcooldownnumber1, spellcooldownnumber2, spellcooldownnumber3, spellcooldownnumber4, spellcooldownnumber5,
            spellcooldownnumber6, spellcooldownnumber7, spellcooldownnumber8;
    public Image spell1cooldownimage, spell2cooldownimage, spell3cooldownimage, spell4cooldownimage, spell5cooldownimage,
                spell6cooldownimage, spell7cooldownimage, spell8cooldownimage;

    void Start () {
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    }

    void Update () {
        scrollSpells();
        displayCooldowns();
    }

    public void activateSpell(Transform trans)
    {
        switch (activenumber)
        {
            case 0:
                if (spellcooldown1 == 0 || spellcooldown1 < Time.time)
                {
                    Instantiate(spell1, trans.position, trans.rotation);
                    Spell spell = spell1.GetComponent<Spell>();
                    spellcooldown1 = Time.time + spell.cooldowntime;
                    spellcooldownnumber1 = spell.cooldowntime;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (spellcooldown2 == 0 || spellcooldown2 < Time.time)
                {
                    Instantiate(spell2, trans.position, trans.rotation);
                    Spell spell = spell2.GetComponent<Spell>();
                    spellcooldown2 = Time.time + spell.cooldowntime;
                    spellcooldownnumber2 = spell.cooldowntime;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (spellcooldown3 == 0 || spellcooldown3 < Time.time)
                {
                    Instantiate(spell3, trans.position, trans.rotation);
                    Spell spell = spell3.GetComponent<Spell>();
                    spellcooldown3 = Time.time + spell.cooldowntime;
                    spellcooldownnumber3 = spell.cooldowntime;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (spellcooldown4 == 0 || spellcooldown4 < Time.time)
                {
                    Instantiate(spell4, trans.position, trans.rotation);
                    Spell spell = spell4.GetComponent<Spell>();
                    spellcooldown4 = Time.time + spell.cooldowntime;
                    spellcooldownnumber4 = spell.cooldowntime;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (spellcooldown5 == 0 || spellcooldown5 < Time.time)
                {
                    Instantiate(spell5, trans.position, trans.rotation);
                    Spell spell = spell5.GetComponent<Spell>();
                    spellcooldown5 = Time.time + spell.cooldowntime;
                    spellcooldownnumber5 = spell.cooldowntime;
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if (spellcooldown6 == 0 || spellcooldown6 < Time.time)
                {
                    Instantiate(spell6, trans.position, trans.rotation);
                    Spell spell = spell6.GetComponent<Spell>();
                    spellcooldown6 = Time.time + spell.cooldowntime;
                    spellcooldownnumber6 = spell.cooldowntime;
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                if (spellcooldown7 == 0 || spellcooldown7 < Time.time)
                {
                    Instantiate(spell7, trans.position, trans.rotation);
                    Spell spell = spell7.GetComponent<Spell>();
                    spellcooldown7 = Time.time + spell.cooldowntime;
                    spellcooldownnumber7 = spell.cooldowntime;
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                if (spellcooldown8 == 0 || spellcooldown8 < Time.time)
                {
                    Instantiate(spell8, trans.position, trans.rotation);
                    Spell spell = spell8.GetComponent<Spell>();
                    spellcooldown8 = Time.time + spell.cooldowntime;
                    spellcooldownnumber8 = spell.cooldowntime;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    void scrollSpells()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f) // forward
        {
            if (activenumber == 7)
                activenumber = 0;
            else
                activenumber++;
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f) // backwards
        {
            if (activenumber == 0)
                activenumber = 7;
            else
                activenumber--;
        }
    }

    void displayCooldowns()
    {
        spell1cooldownimage.fillAmount = (spellcooldown1- Time.time) / spellcooldownnumber1;
        spell2cooldownimage.fillAmount = (spellcooldown2 - Time.time) / spellcooldownnumber2;
        spell3cooldownimage.fillAmount = (spellcooldown3 - Time.time) / spellcooldownnumber3;
        spell4cooldownimage.fillAmount = (spellcooldown4 - Time.time) / spellcooldownnumber4;
        spell5cooldownimage.fillAmount = (spellcooldown5 - Time.time) / spellcooldownnumber5;
        spell6cooldownimage.fillAmount = (spellcooldown6 - Time.time) / spellcooldownnumber6;
        spell7cooldownimage.fillAmount = (spellcooldown7 - Time.time) / spellcooldownnumber7;
        spell8cooldownimage.fillAmount = (spellcooldown8 - Time.time) / spellcooldownnumber8;      
    }
}
```

I hope someone could review this code for me and give me tips about how I use inheritance or how my SpellHandlerGUI can be improved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of a lot of repetition in `activateSpell()` by storing things in arrays and accessing them by the `activeNumber`.  You can set up your arrays like so:

```
private GameObject[] spells;
private float[] spellCooldowns;
private float[] spellCooldownNumbers;

void Start () {
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    spells = new[] { spell1, spell2...
    spellCooldowns = new[] { spellcooldown1, spellcooldown2...
    spellCooldownNumbers = new[] { spellcooldownnumber1, spellcooldownnumber2...
}
```

You can then write activateSpell like this:

```
public void activateSpell(Transform trans)
{
    int i = activenumber;
    if (spellCooldowns[i] == 0 || spellCooldowns[i] < Time.time)
    {
        Instantiate(spells[i], trans.position, trans.rotation);
        Spell spell = spells[i].GetComponent<Spell>();
        spellCooldowns[i] = Time.time + spell.cooldowntime;
        spellCooldownNumber[i] = spell.cooldowntime;
    }
}
```

If you want, you can create a class to store a spell, its cooldown, and its cooldown number, so then you would only need to create one array.

You can use modulo arithmetic to make sure a number is within a certain range.  `scrollSpells()` can be written like this:

```
void scrollSpells()
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f) // forward
    {
        activenumber = (activenumber + 1) % 7;
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f) // backwards
    {
        activenumber = (activenumber + 7 - 1) % 7;
    }
}
```

Instead of hard coding in `7` you can use the number of spells in the array.

```
void scrollSpells()
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f) // forward
    {
        activenumber = (activenumber + 1) % spells.Count();
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f) // backwards
    {
        activenumber = (activenumber + spells.Count() - 1) % spells.Count();
    }
}
```

Variable names should be lowerCamelCase, so `activenumber` should be `activeNumber`.  Method names should be UpperCamelCase, so `activateSpell()` should be `ActivateSpell()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very constructive and I can use a lot of it :)

Answer (score 1):

1 . Your public fields in the `Spell` as far as I see aren't used,you declare a bunch of redundant variables when you already have such in your class.

2 . You can replace the switch case easily if your spell class know's a little bit more about what the actual spell is, if you don't want to expose too much data you might want to create a helper class, once you have this you can iterate over an array of `Spell` objects a class that has access to all the properties used in here :

```
            if (spellcooldown1 == 0 || spellcooldown1 < Time.time)
            {
                Instantiate(spell1, trans.position, trans.rotation);
                Spell spell = spell1.GetComponent<Spell>();
                spellcooldown1 = Time.time + spell.cooldowntime;
                spellcooldownnumber1 = spell.cooldowntime;
            }
```

3 . Your `Spell` class should probably have a boolean function which checks if the spell is off-cooldown so you can replace the if statements with the function call

```
public bool IsOnCooldown()
{
    return spellcooldown == 0 || spellcooldown < Time.time;
}
```

Another function maybe called `CastSpell` which might require some parameters like the `gameObject` you can even do this as an extension method so you dont always pass the spell that you need to cast, it should probably execute all this code :

```
                Instantiate(spell1, trans.position, trans.rotation);
                Spell spell = spell1.GetComponent<Spell>();
                spellcooldown1 = Time.time + spell.cooldowntime;
                spellcooldownnumber1 = spell.cooldowntime;
```

Like this you are restricting the access to your spell class which is one of the most important things in programming. If you now have the `Spell` array iterating over it would be trivial :

```
foreach(Spell spell in Spells)
{
    if(!spell.IsOnCooldown)
    {
        spell.CastSpell(...someParameters);
    }
}
```

**Note** You can add a function which checks if an appropriate keyboard key was pressed so you can trigger the spell this way.

4 . You might want to have something that allows you to check what cooldown is left on the spell like this you can easily work with the images/icons - a *public property* with a private setter or just a short function which returns an `int` you can decide what it will return maybe even the whole formula `(spellcooldown1- Time.time) / spellcooldownnumber1` or just parts of it.

5 . After You've finished point #4 you can again declare an `Image` array, iterate over it with a `for` loop so you can combine it with the `Spell` array something like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < Icons.Length; i++)
{
    Icons[i].fillAmount = Spells[i].GetCurrentCooldown();
}
```

This requires you to have your `Spell[]` sorted properly and also `GetCurrentCooldown` is the function I spoke of in point #4.

6 . Your `scrollSpells` method contains some magic numbers which are bad practice and should be avoided, aside from that you can use the ternary operator to shorten your lines there : `activenumber = activenumber == 7 ? 0 : activenumber + 1;`

7 . Your variable naming should look like this : `spellCooldown` or `spell_cooldown` instead of `spellcooldown`, function names should start with capital letters `DisplayCooldowns` rather than `displayCooldowns`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see what I can do with some parts yeah, but the Spell class is an parent class and everytime I click the spell button it makes a new spell that dissapears after a while, so storing the cooldown in the spell itsself might not work as I want it too :)

Comment: You should be using property not field and make a constructor which takes those value's as parameters, you might have to give up on the inspector view of the variable but I'm not entirely sure.